# how to show matplotlib graph in flask through html (Without saving image)

Tags: python, html, matplotlib, flask

So I don't want to use plt.savefig and want to render my graph dynamically. Please look into this, it is saving the graph and then rendering -

```
def get_graph(pressure, flow, fr_value):
    fig = plt.figure()
    img=io.BytesIO()
    plt.plot(flow, pressure)
    plt.savefig(img,format='png')
    img.seek(0)
    plot_url = base64.b64encode(img.getvalue()).decode()
    return plot_url
```

and my flask app -

```
    plot_url = graph.get_graph(int(pressure), int(flow), fr_value)  # figure from get_graph url

    return render_template('plot.html', url=plot_url)
```

html -

```
<body>
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{url}}" alt="Chart" height="auto" width="60%">
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the non-obvious problems I ran into when trying to do that was discovering the need for

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('agg')
```

so that matplotlib wouldn't try to use tkinker. Try adding that.

An alternative approach is to provide a separate method to render the image. I have a working example of that [here](https://github.com/davewsmith/play/tree/master/matplotlib-flask) that you're welcome to borrow code from.